# Error installing abp cli: source was found on

Tags: abp

When trying to install abp it shows me the following:

`dotnet tool install -g Volo.Abp.Cli`

`Package source mapping is enabled, but no source was found on the package id. specified package: volo.abp.cli. See the package source mapping documentation at https://aka.ms/nuget-package-source-mapping for more details.`

What could be the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are encountering indicates that there is an issue with the package source mapping. Try adding the source or execute the following command:

> `dotnet tool install -g Volo.Abp.Cli --add-source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`